# Al completar el formulario, no valida el campo TITULO y no crea la carpeta imagenes

Tags: php, mysqli, variables

Estoy estudiando y practicando PHP. He creado una página de una inmobiliaria, por tanto, cree un formulario en el cual el usuario ingresa los datos de un inmueble y despues se debe visualizar en la página principal. En el momento que completo el formulario y doy clic para enviar y crear la carpeta imagenes, me aparece la alerta "Debes añadir un titulo", aun cuando se le estan pasando el valor asignado, aplico el var_dump($_POST); pero sigue sin validar.

```
array(7) {
  ["titulo"]=>
  string(19) "Casa en el bosque 3"
  ["precio"]=>
  string(8) "18989898"
  ["descripcion"]=>
  string(124) "casa bonita en la playa con varios lujos y mucho más..."
  ["habitaciones"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["wc"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["estacionamiento"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["vendedor"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

He revisado el código varias veces,

Por eso acudo a ustedes, que tienen experiencia y me guíen.

Adjunto código y print.
Tanto el html como php se encuentran un mismo archivo que llame crear.php

```
     <?php
    require '../../includes/funciones.php';
    incluirTemplate('header');
 
    // Base de datos
    require '../../includes/config/database.php';
    $db = conectarDB();
 
    // Consultar para obtener los vendedores
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM vendedores";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $consulta);
 
    // Arreglo con mensajes de errores
    $errores = [];
 
    $titulo = '';
    $precio = '';
    $descripcion = '';
    $habitaciones = '';
    $wc = '';
    $estacionamiento = '';
    $vendedorId = '';
 
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
 
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($_POST);
        echo "</pre>";
 
        /*
        Sanitizar      
        */ 
        $$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,  $_POST['titulo'] );
        $precio = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,  $_POST['precio'] );
        $descripcion = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,  $_POST['descripcion'] );
        $habitaciones = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,  $_POST['habitaciones'] );
        $wc = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,  $_POST['wc'] );
        $estacionamiento = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,  $_POST['estacionamiento'] );
        $vendedorId = mysqli_real_escape_string( $db,  $_POST['vendedor'] );
        $creado = date('Y/m/d');
 
        // Asignar files hacia una variable
        $imagen = $_FILES['imagen'];
 
        if(!$titulo) {
            $errores[] = "Debes añadir un titulo";
        }
 
        if(!$precio) {
            $errores[] = 'El Precio es Obligatorio';
        }
 
        if( strlen( $descripcion ) < 50 ) {
            $errores[] = 'La descripción es obligatoria y debe tener al menos 50 caracteres';
        }
 
        if(!$habitaciones) {
            $errores[] = 'El Número de habitaciones es obligatorio';
        }
        
        if(!$wc) {
            $errores[] = 'El Número de Baños es obligatorio';
        }
 
        if(!$estacionamiento) {
            $errores[] = 'El Número de lugares de Estacionamiento es obligatorio';
        }
 
        if(!$vendedorId) {
            $errores[] = 'Elige un vendedor';
        }   
 
    
        if(!$imagen['name'] || $imagen['error'] ) {
            $errores[] = 'La Imagen es Obligatoria';
        }
 
        // Validar por tamaño (1mb máximo)
        $medida = 1000 * 1000;
 
 
        if($imagen['size'] > $medida ) {
            $errores[] = 'La Imagen es muy pesada';
        }
        
        // Revisar que el array de errores este vacio
        if(empty($errores)) {
 
            /** SUBIDA DE ARCHIVOS */
 
            // Crear carpeta
            $carpetaImagenes = '../../imagenes/';
 
            if(!is_dir($carpetaImagenes)) {
                mkdir($carpetaImagenes);
            }
 
            exit;
 
            // Insertar en la base de datos
            $query = " INSERT INTO propiedades (titulo, precio, descripcion, habitaciones, wc, estacionamiento, creado, vendedorId ) VALUES ( '$titulo', '$precio', '$descripcion', '$habitaciones', '$wc', '$estacionamiento', '$creado', '$vendedorId' ) ";
 
            $resultado = mysqli_query($db, $query);
            if($resultado) {
                // Redireccionar al usuario.
                echo'<script language="javascript">
                        swal({   
                            title: "Insertado Correctamente", 
                            text: "Has agregado correctamente la propiedad con sus valores.",
                            type: "success",
                            closeOnConfirm: false, 
                            showLoaderOnConfirm: true, 
                        },
                        function(){
                        setTimeout(function()
                        {
                        javascript:window.location.replace("http://localhost/curso-web-completo/bienes-raices/admin/index.php");
                    }, 2000); });</script>';
            }
 
        }
 
    }
?>
 
<main class="contenedor seccion">
    <h1>Crear</h1>
 
    <a href="../index.php" class="boton boton-verde">Volver</a>
 
    <?php foreach($errores as $error): ?>
    <div class="alerta error">
        <?php echo $error; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
 
    <form class="formulario" method="POST" action="./crear.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Información General</legend>
 
            <label for="titulo">Titulo:</label>
            <input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo Propiedad" value="<?php echo $titulo; ?>">
 
            <label for="precio">Precio:</label>
            <input type="number" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Precio Propiedad"
                value="<?php echo $precio; ?>">
 
            <label for="imagen">Imagen:</label>
            <input type="file" id="imagen" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" name="imagen">
 
            <label for="descripcion">Descripción:</label>
            <textarea id="descripcion" name="descripcion"><?php echo $descripcion; ?></textarea>
 
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Información Propiedad</legend>
 
            <label for="habitaciones">Habitaciones:</label>
            <input type="number" id="habitaciones" name="habitaciones" placeholder="Ej: 3" min="1" max="9"
                value="<?php echo $habitaciones; ?>">
 
            <label for="wc">Baños:</label>
            <input type="number" id="wc" name="wc" placeholder="Ej: 3" min="1" max="9" value="<?php echo $wc; ?>">
 
            <label for="estacionamiento">Estacionamiento:</label>
            <input type="number" id="estacionamiento" name="estacionamiento" placeholder="Ej: 3" min="1" max="9"
                value="<?php echo $estacionamiento; ?>">
 
        </fieldset>
 
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Vendedor</legend>
 
            <select name="vendedor">
                <option value="">-- Seleccione --</option>
                <?php while($vendedor =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado) ) : ?>
                <option <?php echo $vendedorId === $vendedor['id'] ? 'selected' : ''; ?>
                    value="<?php echo $vendedor['id']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $vendedor['nombre'] . " " . $vendedor['apellido']; ?> </option>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
 
        <input type="submit" value="Crear Propiedad" class="boton boton-verde">
    </form>
</main>
 
<?php
    incluirTemplate('footer');
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Brayam, el código y los mensajes de error deben ir como texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes que los contienen, y agregues el contenido de ellas como texto, de esa forma tu pregunta será mejor recibida, y evitarás recibir votos negativos.  aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 0):

Es que no has asignado el valor en las variables que usas, debes poner algo así:

```
   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

       echo "<pre>";
       var_dump($_POST);
       echo "</pre>";

       $titulo = $_POST["titulo"];
       $precio = $_POST["precio"];
       $descripcion = $_POST["descripcion"];
       $habitaciones = $_POST["habitaciones"];
       $wc = $_POST["wc"];
       $estacionamiento = $_POST["estacionamiento"];
       $vendedorId = $_POST["vendedor"];
```

Donde `$_POST["titulo"]` hace referencia al valor del input cuyo `name` es `titulo`, es decir este:

```
<input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo Propiedad" value="<?php echo $titulo; ?>">
```

Tambien puedes hacer una validación por HTML, simplemente agregando `required` al input

```
<input type="text" id="titulo" name="titulo" placeholder="Titulo Propiedad" value="<?php echo $titulo; ?>" required>
```